# Formsubmit.co not working - no action on submit

Tags: form-submit

I refactored my website (I'm very junior!) and I can't get the subscription via FormSubmit to work, even though it used to work before.  I must be doing something wrong, but for the life of me I can't figure it out.

The issue was resolved by replacing the div to a button.  Here is the code that works newsletter subscription:

```
<form id="newsletter" action="https://formsubmit.co/fb6a7b8aa5477c50770549512f505741" method="POST">
    <div class="email-subscription-container">
        <input type="email" name="email" placeholder='Enter your email address' class="email-input" required />
        
        <input type="hidden" name="_next" value="https://www.funficient.com/subscribed.html">
        <input type="hidden" name="_subject" value="New newsletter subscription!">
        <input type="text" name="_honey" style="display:none">
        <input type="hidden" name="_captcha" value="true">

        <button type="submit" class="submit-button">Subscribe</button>
    </div>
</form>
```

When I tested it on my local environment I managed to get an activation request which I clicked, but now it's just not working at all.  It's as if the POST method doesn't do anything. After troubleshooting it is because I'm using a div and not a button.

It used to work before I refactored, and even after I refactored the form worked, but not the newsletter subscription.  I tried to de-activate github pages which I used in development to test as I thought it might conflict.

I also tried to use an unmasked email address to 'reset' it, but that also didn't work.

Comment: I fixed it!  By changing the div to a button.  Yeah!